# Set rootViewController not release other View Controllers in navigation

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, rootviewcontroller

My app is when duplicate log-in, i will force them go to LoginViewController (not the root view).
But my problems is when i set rootViewController, other ViewController in navigation Controller not dealloc. it causes crash app>
Could u please help me to solve the problem! thanks a millions times.

Plus: when pop view controller or replace view controller it works

Comment: Please clarify your problem. Because above informations is not enough to identify your problem.

Comment: A little code never killed nobody. Please take a look at how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) example.